# Julia equivalent to R `as.numeric()`

Tags: julia

This is a straightforward Q:

*Is there an equivalent to R's `as.numeric(vec)` in Julia?*

In R, I'd do the following:

```r
x <- c(True, False, False, True)
as.numeric(x)
```

And get `1, 0, 0, 1` as a result.

Is there a function equivalent in Julia?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to convert a vector of booleans to a vector of integers. You can do it in Julia like so:

```
x=[true, false, false, true] 
println(typeof(x)) #Vector{Bool}
y=Int.(x) 
println(typeof(y)) #Vector{Int64}
```

Comment: This also works for other types, like `Float32.(x)`, `UInt8.(x)`, `Complex{Rational{Int}}.(x)`. It's not clear to me what number type 'numeric' should be, actually. I wonder why that means 'integer' and not 'float', for example.

Comment: In R, they can be either integer or float.